# django - How to create a form inside a detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am creating an online debate app using Django. I have used a class-based list view to create different topics using `pk` and once I click on the topic it takes me to its details page and once I go to the detail page I need two text-boxes to enter my for point and against point and after entering the point I need to display the point below the text-box. I have created a list of topics but I'm unable to do the text-box to that particular page.

This is my models.py

```
class DebateModel(models.Model):
    title = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True,null= True)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 5000 , null=True,blank=True)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
     
class ForModel(models.Model):
    DebateModel = models.ForeignKey(DebateModel,related_name="for_point",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 5000)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s  %s' % (self.DebateModel.title, self.body)
    
class AgainstModel(models.Model):
    DebateModel = models.ForeignKey(DebateModel,related_name="against_point",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length = 5000)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s  %s' % (self.DebateModel.title, self.body)
```

this is my forms.py

```
class EditFor(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = ForModel
    fields = ('body',)
    widgets = {
    'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }
```

this is my views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = DebateModel
    template_name = "debate/home.html"

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
   model = DebateModel
   template_name = "debate/content.html"
   context_object_name = 'debate'

class AddForView(CreateView):
   model = ForModel
   template_name="debate/content.html"
   form_class = EditFor
   def form_valid(self,form):
       form.instance.DebateModel_id = self.kwargs['pk']
       return super().form_valid(form)
       success_url = reverse_lazy('debate/home.html')
```

this is my urls.py

```
path('',HomeView.as_view(),name = "home"),
path('article/<int:pk>',ArticleDetailView.as_view(),name = "debate-detail"),
path('article/<int:pk>/forpoint',AddForView.as_view(),name="add_For"),
```

This is my content.html

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">for</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">against</button>
<form method="post" action="Add_For/">
 {%csrf_token%}
 </form>
 <script>
      function myFunction() {
      var x = document.createElement("TEXTAREA");
      var t = document.createTextNode("enter your for point");
      var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
      y.setAttribute("type", "submit");
      document.body.appendChild(y);
      x.appendChild(t);
      document.body.appendChild(x);
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: you need to post your codes as well.

Comment: @PadalaKavya It is better to post the code as text within a code block.

Comment: @AhmedNourEldeen I have updated with code.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko  I have added my forms.py and also edited the code.

Comment: @arjun I have added my code.

Comment: @PadalaKavya you're still hardcoding the `action` in `form`. Dont do that. Use [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) please